# Render a component on a route only if it is redirected from another route after form submission

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, frontend

I visited to a url "https://domainname.com/passwords/new" which asks me to enter my email to send a reset password link to my gmail account. When I enters my email and submit then the url changes to "https://domainname.com/passwords" and it renders 
 "An email is sent to your account successfully". But if I manually navigates to the same url("https://domainname.com/passwords") it shows me 404. How to do it with reactjs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a variable (think local or session storage) after the user successfully resets their password. Then, when rendering the /passwords route, read that variable. If it exists, render the component, if not, redirect to a 404. Works pretty much the same way as the [authenticated routes](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow) example.